# IFrame Grand Parent Record on Grand Child Record

Tags: visualforce, iframe, clickjacking

I'm trying to IFrame a Record from my Project Object to it's Grandchild the Case Object. There is an Object called Related_Doctor that sits in-between.

When I use the below code I get a "salesforce.com refused to connect."

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" readonly="true"  standardController="Case" tabStyle="Case">
<apex:iframe src="/{!Case.Related_Doctor__r.Project__c}?isdtp=vw" scrolling="true" id="theFrame" />
<script>document.getElementById('theFrame').height = window.innerHeight ;</script>
```

[image: Error Image]

1. I've also confirmed that Clickjack settings are off (see below)
2. When I use Chrome's inspect element and open the link referenced for the IFrame in a new tab the pages loads as expected.

[image: Clickjack Disabled]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visualforce pages are served from `visual.force` domain and standard record pages are served from `salesforce` or `lightning.force` domain. The error you are seeing is not because of salesforce but because of browser security.

You can notice in chrome console:

> Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading 'https://myDomain.my.salesforce.com/apexpages/devmode/devConsoleViewStateMetadataReceiver.apexp?sfdcIFrameOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Fmy-own-org-dev-ed--c.ap6.visual.force.com': 'ALLOW-FROM https://myDomain.ap6.visual.force.com' is not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored.

As a work around, you can create a page and implement `apex:detail`:

DemoPage.vfp:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardController="Account" >
    <apex:detail />
</apex:page>
```

and use it:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" readonly="true"  standardController="Case" tabStyle="Case">
    <apex:iframe src="/apex/DemoPage?id={!Case.AccountId}&myattr=myval" scrolling="true" id="theFrame" />
    <script>
        document.getElementById('theFrame').height = window.innerHeight ;
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: The above worked perfectly!